# Unable to install grub on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, grub

I am unable to install `grub` on `Fedora`. I ran following commands,

```
# fallocate -l 1G archlinux.raw
#  fdisk archlinux.raw <<< '
$ > o
$ > n
$ > p
$ > 1
$ >
$ >
$ > a
$ > w'
# losetup -f --show archlinux.raw
# kpartx -a /dev/loop0
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p1
# TMPDIR=/full/path/to/temporary/directory
# mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 $TMPDIR
# grub-install --boot-directory=$TMPDIR/boot /dev/loop0
Installing for i386-pc platform.
  Volume group "loop3p1" not found
  Cannot process volume group loop3p1
  Volume group "loop3p1" not found
  Cannot process volume group loop3p1
grub-install: error: disk `lvm/loop3p1' not found.
```

Comment: losetup does not guarantee the image will mounted on /dev/loop0 - TMPDIR seems incorrect - you also need root-directory set to the mount point as I think it is picking up your host lvm

Comment: i m new to fedora, i want to create a bootable qcow2 disk image. i want to use grub bootloader. plz suggest me, where i am going wrong